# How do I make the Dash open up fullscreen in 2D?

Tags: unity-2d, unity-dash

How to make the dash in Unity 2D open up full-screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 12.04

Fortunately this is very simple now in 12.04

First open the Dash

[image]

Then click the maximize button:

[image]

This remembers the setting between Dash openings and session re-logins.

Answer (score 5):

### 11.04

I've found a workaround to do that.

Open the file `/usr/share/unity-2d/places/dash.qml`.

Find this code:

```
        if (currentPage != undefined) {
        currentPage.visible = false
    }
    currentPage = page
    currentPage.visible = true
    dashView.dashMode = DashDeclarativeView.FullScreenMode //AND ADD THIS LINE
}
```

NOTE: I've tested this on the daily build of Unity-2d from PPA, I'm not sure it works on the Natty version.

EDIT: The code on the Natty version it's similar, and is between the line 42 and 50.

Answer (score 4):

### 11.10

This works in 11.10: add the same line, not in 'activateHome', put it it 'Connections':

```
Connections {
        target: dashView
        onActiveChanged: {
            if (!dashView.active) {
                /* FIXME: currentPage needs to stop pointing to pageLoader.item
                          that is about to be invalidated otherwise a crash
                          occurs because SearchEntry has a binding that refers
                          to currentPage and tries to access it.
                   Ref.: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/817896
                         https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-20692
                */
                deactivateActiveLens()
                currentPage = undefined
                pageLoader.source = ""
            }
        dashView.dashMode = DashDeclarativeView.FullScreenMode //THIS IS THE NEW LINE
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

### 11.04

Just found how to fix it in Natty. Add the line:

```
dashView.dashMode = DashDeclarativeView.FullScreenMode
```

in function activateHome(). By example:

```
function activateHome() {
  pageLoader.source = "Home.qml"
  /* Take advantage of the fact that the loaded qml is local and setting
     the source loads it immediately making pageLoader.item valid */
  activatePage(pageLoader.item)
  pageLoader.item.shortcutsActive = true
  dashView.activePlaceEntry = ""
  dashView.dashMode = DashDeclarativeView.FullScreenMode // ADD THIS LINE
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Hopefully this article covers what you want:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/quick-tip-enable-full-screen-dash-in-natty-desktop/

Comment: thats for unity 3d

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.