# Why doesn't the Unity-2D dashboard remain fullscreen after I click the fullscreen button?

Tags: unity-dash, unity-2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make the Dash open up fullscreen in 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30882/how-do-i-make-the-dash-open-up-fullscreen-in-2d)

My notebook has a widescreen display of 1280x800 and for some reason the Unity-2D dashboard always insists on opening up using only about 60% of my screen.

At the bottom right of the dashboard is an icon. When I click this icon the dashboard expands to full screen. Great! It looks good and doesn't feel so cramped on my display..

However when I close the dashboard and re-open it again (to find a file or program) it always reverts back to non-fullscreen. I have to open the dashboard and and constantly click that fullscreen button in the bottom right - it's really annoying.

Once I've indicated my preference shouldn't the dashboard remember what that preference was? That's how the dashboard's "Filter Results" works - if I expand it and re-open the dashboard it stays expanded. Why are these two behaviors not consistent?

If I'm not suppose to make the dashboard full screen then why even include the button to expand it to full screen if it' only going to revert back?

Answer (score 0):

My dash, on ubuntu 11.10, do now have any bottom-right expand button. It is in the top left corner, over the launcher, as you can see in this image:

[image: unity dash in ubuntu 11.10]

Clicking on full screen button keeps the dash in full screen for any following openings.

Comment: That is Unity, not Unity 2D. Unity 2D doesn't have those buttons, but a button in the lower right corner.

Comment: woops...sorry! Haven't seen the 2d part....

Answer (score 0):

Since your question starts with a 'why', I guess the answer is: because the designers thought it would be a good idea to have a dash that only covers a certain part of the screen for large displays. Why they though that is a good idea? No clue.

If you ask "how" to open always in fullscreen, then your question is a duplicate of e.g. [How do I make the Dash open up fullscreen in 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30882/how-do-i-make-the-dash-open-up-fullscreen-in-2d)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that drawing the entire screen is more work than only drawing what's necessary. There's no reason why you shouldn't be able to choose to always have it draw full screen, as long as you can easily change it back, so I guess that'll be possible in the next version. Unity and Unity 2D are both young.