# Am I able to set Unity's dash full screen as default?

Tags: unity, unity-2d, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make the Dash open up fullscreen in 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30882/how-do-i-make-the-dash-open-up-fullscreen-in-2d)

I'd like to click on the Ubuntu buttom and see the dash in full screen as default. Am I able to do it using Ubuntu 11.10 and Unity 2D?

Answer (score 11):

just maximze it once and all future dash shall open in maximized fullscreen

[image]

click on the the third button from left on the top left corner

Comment: Thank you for your attention, but I'm using Unity 2D right now. In Unity 2D it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2):

In **11.10 & unity-2d** I believe it may be determined by screen resolution, not sure exactly what the cutoff is.

If you get the non-fullscreen by default then that's what you'll see each time the Dash is opened,  you can only get fullscreen by clicking on.

There is this thread with 2 posted code changes, don't see either working here on a laptop @ 1200X800

[How do I make the Dash open up fullscreen in 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30882/how-do-i-make-the-dash-open-up-fullscreen-in-2d)

As far as form-factor, same deal on this laptop, fullscreen only thru click on, always opens non-fullscreen.

(While not needed in unity-3d,  form-factor to netbook does cause a fullscreen dash until the dash is restored, then the gsetting is auto set back to Desktop

A current related bug on unity-2d

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/797081